# How to set shell locale in Java JSch

Tags: shell, ssh, environment-variables, locale, jsch

I am using [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to perform SSH functionality from one machine to another machine. I am using English text to compare the result say like *"No result found"* or *"No command"*. Assuming a scenario if the remote machine o/p is in another language, then how do we compare it?

Please correct me, should I use something like

```
jschSession.setConfig("Locale","en_US");
```

for that session?

Or is there any other setting?

Comment: What are those results of? A remote shell command? Local JSch error message? SSH server error message?

Comment: Hi Martin, yes it is a remote shell command output 'No result found' and  'No such command' as of now in English. I have not checked yet by changing the locale of remote machine. I am trying to write possible validation condition.

Answer (score 1):

First, I do not think that comparing error message is a reliable approach.

You should better test command exit code.

---

Anyway, the locale of the shell session is controlled by `LANG` environment variable:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ ls nonexisting
ls: cannot access nonexisting: No such file or directory
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
$ ls nonexisting
ls: Zugriff auf nonexisting nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

---

In JSch you can set the environment variables using one of `ChannelSession.setEnv` method overloads:

```java
public void setEnv(Hashtable env)
public void setEnv(String name, String value)
public void setEnv(byte[] name, byte[] value)
```

That works only if the server support the SSH `env` request.

---

Or you can of course just execute the `export` command as any other.

---

Note that not all commands will reflect the `LANG` variable. And not all locales are available on all servers.